# GCM activity not starting as a secondary activity

Tags: android-intent

How do i start an activity that is using GCM as an intent? because if i start the The class from intent the application just stalls/freez. but if i run the class as a main activity it works fine.

Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Figured out that GCMIntentService class should be in the same package as the main activity of the Application. Its working now!